# Why isn't the most appropriate constructor called in this case?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, copy-constructor, enable-if

Consider the following class:

```cpp
class foo {
    int data;
public:
    template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_constructible<int, T>::value>>
    foo(const T& i) : data{ i } { cout << "Value copy ctor" << endl; }

    template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_constructible<int, T>::value>>
    foo(T&& i) : data{ i } { cout << "Value move ctor" << endl; }

    foo(const foo& other) : data{ other.data } { cout << "Copy ctor" << endl; }

    foo(foo&& other) : data{ other.data } { cout << "Move ctor" << endl; }

    operator int() { cout << "Operator int()" << endl; return data; }
};
```

*Of course it doesn't make much sense to take a single `int` by any kind of reference, but this is just an example. The `data` member could be very expensive to copy, hence all the move semantics.*

That fancy template basically enables any type from which `data` can be constructed. So a `foo` object can be constructed either by copying or moving a value of any type that satisfies this criteria, or simply by copying or moving another object of type `foo`. Pretty straight forward so far.

The problem occurs when you try to do something like this:

```cpp
foo obj1(42);
foo obj2(obj1);
```

What this *should* do (at lest in my opinion) is to construct the first object by moving the value 42 into it (since it's an rvalue), and then construct the second object by copying the first object. So what this should print out is:

```
Value move ctor
Copy ctor
```

But what it actually prints out is:

```
Value move ctor
Operator int
Value move ctor
```

The first object gets constructed just fine, no problem there. But instead of calling the copy constructor to construct the second object, the program converts the first object into another type (via the conversion we defined) and then calls another constructor of `foo` which can move from that type (since it's an rvalue at that point).

I find this very strange, and it's definitely not the behavior I would want from this piece of code. I think it makes more sense to just call the copy constructor upon constructing the second object, as that seems way more trivial given the type of argument I supplied.

Can anyone explain what happens here? Of course I understand that since there's a user-defined conversion to int, this is a perfectly valid path to take, but I cannot make sense of it. Why would the compiler refuse to simply call the constructor which has the exact same argument type as the supplied value? Wouldn't that be the most trivial thing to do, therefore the default behavior? Calling the conversion operator does perform a copy as well, so I don't think that is faster or more optimal than simply calling the copy constructor either.

Comment: Shouldn't it be is_constructible<T,int> instead of the other way around as you currently have it?

Comment: @Alejandro Correct, that also [solves the issue](https://ideone.com/6SRrGr).

Comment: @nwp I'm confused. According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible), that thing returns whether or not the **fist thing** can be constructed **from the second thing**. And since I'm constructing my `data` member (which is an `int`) from the `T` argument, this should be the correct order. I'm only accepting types from which I can construct my `int`.

Comment: What you said really does solve the problem, but I'm even more confused now than before :D

Comment: What @Alejandro said only works because T is int in the example. If you declare data as any non-primitive type (call it bar) and int isn't constructible from bar then those constructors would be excluded from is_constructible<T, bar> because for T : int then int has no visible method to construct itself from bar. However is_constructible<bar, T> for T : int will succeed if bar declares a public constructor that takes int. 
Correct me if I have interpreted the usage incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your template "move" constructor (with `T = foo &`) has a parameter of type `foo &`, which is a better match than your copy constructor, since that only takes `const foo &`. Your template constructor then fills `data` by converting `i` to `int`, invoking `operator int()`.

The simplest immediate fix could be to use `enable_if` to restrict your move constructor to move operations: if `T` is deduced as an lvalue reference type (meaning your `T&& i` would collapse to an lvalue reference too), force a substitution failure.

```
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_constructible<int, T>::value>,
                      typename = enable_if_t<!is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>>
foo(T&& i) : data( std::move(i) ) { cout << "Value move ctor" << endl; }
```

Note: since your parameter has a name, inside the constructor, just like all other named objects, it's an lvalue. Given that you want to move from it, you can use `std::move`.

More generally, you could use perfect forwarding (accepting both lvalues and rvalues), and only remove `foo` itself as a special exception:

```
template <typename T, typename = enable_if_t<is_constructible<int, T>::value>
                    , typename = enable_if_t<!is_same<decay_t<T>, foo>::value>
foo(T&& i) : data( std::forward<T>(i) ) { cout << "Forwarding ctor" << endl; }
```

This would replace your value copy *and* value move constructor.

Another note: `is_constructible<int, T>::value` is a test that tells you whether `data(std::forward<T>(i))` would be well-formed. It does *not* test whether `data{std::forward<T>(i)}` would be well-formed. A `T` for which the result is different is `long`, since the `long` to `int` conversion is a narrowing conversion, and narrowing conversions are not allowed in `{}`.

Comment: This seems like a possible solution, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you explain it a little better?

Comment: This works! I didn't know that an rvalue reference could collapse to an lvalue reference in any way. Thanks!

Comment: The other things you added are very useful too. I didn't think of some of those things. Thanks

Comment: I just watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64) talk... It all makes sense now :) Herb talks about perfect forwarding that `T&&` in like the last quarter of the talk. I wish I had watched this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of `operator int()`.

because of `operator int()`, `obj1` calls `operator int()` and casts itself as an `int`.

---

Possible solutions:

1. use `static_cast<foo>`. this will cast the variable that normally should cast as an `int`, to a `foo`.
2. Anyone please edit this question and fill this. I have no more ideas.

Comment: What @Alejandro said is also true.

Comment: I know why it's possible, but the question really was that why is this the case. Since there IS a constructor that takes the exact type of the argument (`foo`), no conversion should take place. If the class didn't have a constructor that accepted a `foo` object, this would be perfectly normal, but since it does, that should be a more trivial route to take than triggering a conversion. Also, `static_cast` does not solve the problem. The value I pass in is already of type `foo`, there's no need to cast it.

Comment: then maybe you could make an `operator foo()`

Comment: So my problem is that I pass in a `foo` object to a function that does have an overload for exactly a `foo` argument, but that's not the overload that gets called.

Comment: ugh, I'm getting really confused.

Comment: An `operator foo()`? Compilers will simply ignore that, I don't think that will make any change in the actual binary after compiling.

Comment: I tried writing an `operator foo()` but rather unsurprisingly Xcode warns me that it will be ignored. And the result is the same.

Comment: Wow. I really did not expect that.

Comment: @adam10603 This could work. You can just not use the operator int and make a separate function

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that. See the accepted answer

Comment: I see. I also think both is a great practice.